# How to make sure that my virtual machine does not change its IP address when connecting to different networks?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ip-address

I have two virtual machines. First has apache server, and wordpress on virtualhost. Second has mysql server for my wordpress in first vm. Mysql configuration use ip adress of first vm. But when i leave my home and in result leave my home wi-fi, ip adress of first vm is changing when i connect to internet from my phone and my web-site crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is said that by default IP addresses are assigned dynamically, so the IP changes if you are in different network (that is, when you access the Internet through mobile data instead of home wifi). You may [assign static IP address](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04/) to your VM. This is done from inside of your VM.